# Does "I am renting a house" mean I am negotiating with the landlord or I has signed the contract and am living in the house now?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage, tense

When we say "**I am wearing a Tshirt**" (might last a day), we mean "**I have that Tshirt on my body**"

When we don't say "**I am wearing a Tshirt**" to mean "**I am putting on a Tshirt**" (which might last 1 or 2 minutes).

Does "**I am renting a house**" mean I am negotiating with the landlord now (which might last many hours or many days)?

Does "**I am renting a house**" mean I signed the contract already and am living in the house and paying rent monthly now (which might last many months or years)?

Comment: You might not even have got as far as identifying the property or your prospective landlord. ***I am renting a house** near the station next year, if I can find one at a fair price*. Biut even if the rental isn't obviously some time in the future, ***I am renting a house*** doesn't really give any clues as to whether the entire process is fully or partially completed. Context is all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, "I am renting a house near the station next year"? is it future arrangement?

Comment: It might be a "future arrangement". But it *might* simply reflect a "future **intention**" that's nothing more than that as yet.

Comment: Related: [Difference between present continuous and future progressive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133678/) and [Are "present continuous" and "be going to" interchangeable?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116516/), among *many* others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I am renting a house" would generally mean you have completed the negotiations and have a contract, whether you are actually moved in is a bit more questionable though in most cases could safely be assumed. This is from a western US perspective, I suppose this could vary by location.

Comment: Same from a UK perspective. If it's still being negotiated, you can use "in the process of" eg "I'm in the process of renting a house."

Comment: Found on the web, in a forum discussion about student life in Florida - " I'm renting a house next year, if I come back." - Trip Advisor UK - "I'm renting a car next month and plan on driving from Rome to Tuscany" - Reddit - about St Louis (Missouri) - "I'm renting a car next month for 14 days, and I'm looking for ideas on where to park my car that won't cost an arm and a leg"

Answer (score 0):

"I am renting a house / a room" -> that negotiations and contracts are all done would be the most common interpretation.

To mean on-going negotiation, you could say "I am trying to rent a house". And "There's a house I'm trying to rent" would be more unambiguous.